# Как через один класс задать свойство другого класса CSS

Tags: css

Вообщем мне нужно что-бы при наведении на определенный элемент менялась прозрачность другого элемента, на скрине попробую показать наглядно.[image: сам код]

Comment: Покажите html и css текстом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать с помощью определенных [комбинаторов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B#%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B), если объект `pet` является дочерним элементом `left-link-sidebar` или находится на одном уровне вложенности после него. Сделать это можно вот так:

```
.left-link-sidebar:hover .pet {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

если `pet` является дочерним элементом `left-link-sidebar`,
или вот так:

```
.left-link-sidebar:hover ~ .pet {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

если `pet` находится на одном уровне вложенности после `left-link-sidebar`.